# Android sample app not showing up

Tags: android-emulator, android

New Android developer here. I'm following a tutorial at http://www.vogella.de/. The first applications (does temperature conversion) works. The second (does preferences and uses a menu) one never shows up. I've tried using both Helios and Galileo. I've tried re-installing Android SDK. I've tried removing the test device and re-creating it. Others say this tutorial works.

When the other app works, it doesn't get the two lines "No Launcher activity found!" and "The launch will only sync the application packages on the device."

What I see:

```
------------------------------
...] Android Launch!
...] adb is running normally.
...] No Launcher activity found!
...] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
...] Performing sync
...] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'TestDevice'
...] Uploading de.vogella.android.preferences.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
...] Installing de.vogella.android.preferences.apk...
...] Success!
...] \de.vogella.android.preferences\bin\de.vogella.android.preferences.apk installed on device
...] Done!
```

**UPDATE:** here is the text from my Android manifest file

```
<manifest 
    xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";
    package="de.vogella.android.preferences" 
    android:versionCode="1" 
    android:versionName="1.0"> 
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"> 
        <activity android:name=".HelloPreferences" android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity> 
        <activity android:label="Preferences" android:name="Preferences">
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Could you post your AndroidManifest.xml file? I have a feeling it's something in there. Thanks! Welcome to SO :)

Comment: Hmmmm... haven't figured out the reply interface in this forum. "Add Comment" is the only way to post? It doesn't leave room for much.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="de.vogella.android.preferences"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".HelloPreferences"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>

        <activity android:label="Preferences" android:name="Preferences"></activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
</manifest>

Comment: You can edit your question and add the necessary information. And actually it is not a forum, it is a QA site, that is why some things seem to be different ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's the answer, which I had to find elsewhere. It seems that you must have the following element:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

inside your *AndroidManifest.xml* file. Once I added this, then right-clicked on the project name to launch the Android Application, the app then showed up in the menu panel.

Eclipse put this (*intent-filter*) element there for my first experimental application, but it did not do me the favor for the second one I created, which I'm still debugging for yet other (and probably Eclipse-related) reasons. (I probably filled something out wrong when creating the new Android project.)

Comment: And, maybe someday, I'll have enough credits to post something to this Q&A (apparently "not a forum") without having stackoverflow refuse nearly everything I try (links in particular).

Comment: I also face this problem after updated Android SDK to newest(for 4.0.3)......When using wizard to start a new project, it often generate a wrong format manifest.xml, and so this problem occurred.