# launching android widget

Tags: android, widget

I am following http://www.helloandroid.com/files/xmaswidget/android_howto-hellowidget.pdf for developing a widget. I am unable to launch a widget on to the home screen.
When running the application I am getting the errors like No Launcher activity found and
The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
Looking for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you don't have the right setup in your AndroidManifest.xml

Have you seen this post? [Android sample app not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3347569/android-sample-app-not-showing-up)